# Calculate and display value in the last td

Tags: jquery

Goal:
Calculate and display right answer in the last td in the tr by selecting row(s). For instance, if I choose the second row, I would get value 44 and it should be applied in the last td of the row.

Problem:
I know how to do it in javascript but in jQuery.

Need help with the source code in jQuery.

// fullmetalboy

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

        <title>index</title>

    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "checkbox";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            cell3.innerHTML = "22";

            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            cell4.innerHTML = "";


        }

        function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) 
            {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];

                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) 
                {
                    var sdf = 23;


                    //table.deleteRow(i);
                    //rowCount--;
                    //i--;
                }

            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

    </SCRIPT>


    </head>

    <body>

    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <INPUT type="button" value="Calculate selected row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <TR>
            <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
            <TD>1</TD>
            <TD>22</TD>
            <TD></TD>            
        </TR>
    </TABLE>        



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is too vague, you don't have 2 rows and if you added one I would assume you want to display the total so far of the third column in the last td of the tr you selected. But there are too many assumptions to really answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do (you can check more than one columns and the result is calculated for each row):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#calculate').click(function(){
        $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
          var first = parseInt($(this).closest('td').next('td').text(), 10);

         var sec = parseInt($(this).closest('td').next('td').next('td').text(), 10);
            var result = (first*sec);
            $(this).closest('tr').find('td:last').html(result)

        });
    });
});
```

Fidlle here: http://jsfiddle.net/D2uVz/